# debugger does not recognize User settings

Tags: c#, wpf, debugging, visual-studio-debugging, application-settings

I have added the following setting in application settings:

Name:            Type:         Scope:         Value:

ComboBoxItems     String        User     *I didn't insert any value here*

I declared as following:

```
    public partial class postLoginWindow : Window
{
    private readonly string dbConnectionString = Properties.Settings.Default.dbConnectionString;
    private readonly string currentAdminEmail;
    private string ComboBoxItemsString = Properties.Settings.Default.ComboBoxItems;
    public postLoginWindow(string receivedAdminEmail)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        LoadComboBoxValues();
        if (ComboBoxSelectedProfile.Items.IsEmpty)
        {
            ComboBoxSelectedProfile.IsEnabled = false;
            ButtonRenameProfile.IsEnabled = false;
            ButtonChangePermissions.IsEnabled = false;
            ButtonAddNewUser.IsEnabled = false;
            ButtonRemoveUser.IsEnabled = false;
            ButtonDeleteProfile.IsEnabled = false;
        }
...
     }
}
```

This is the method i used to load the string values into the comboBox:

```
private void LoadComboBoxValues()
        {
            string[] ComboBoxRows = ComboBoxItemsString.Split('|');
            foreach (string Row in ComboBoxRows)
            {
                if (Row != "") ComboBoxSelectedProfile.Items.Add(Row);
            }
        }
```

and this is how i add values when i want to save them in the setting string:

```
private void ComboBoxAddItem(string item)
        {
            string[] ComboBoxRows = Properties.Settings.Default.ComboBoxItems.Split('|');
            bool ItemAlreadyExists = false;
            foreach (string Row in ComboBoxRows)
            {
                if (Row == item) ItemAlreadyExists = true;
            }

            if (!ItemAlreadyExists)
            {
                parent.ComboBoxSelectedProfile.Items.Add(item);
                string ComboBoxSavedProfileAsString = TxtProfileName.Text + "|";
                Properties.Settings.Default.ComboBoxItems = Properties.Settings.Default.ComboBoxItems +
                                                            ComboBoxSavedProfileAsString;
                Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
            }
        }
```

Which is done from another window in which i add users.

The problem is: everytime i go into DebugMode for debugging my application it rises up as if the settings string is empty even if i did add some string to it.
So i can't debug my application.

i' appreciate your help very much!

Comment: I test it in the VS2015, the hosting process settings really impacted the result in my side like Weiwei's suggestion, what about this issue in your side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**BIG** Thanks to @Wendy - MSFT, thanks to him/her/it i found the true solution to this problem (which is basically the opposite of what she/he/apache helicopter suggested):

[image: Adding user-settings to be included in Debug-time]

**Please note:**  Unchecked = Debugger WILL **INCLUDE** your user-settings that you added to debugging time.

Checked = Debugger WILL **IGNORE** your user-settings that you added to debugging time.

Answer (score 1):

Please checked "Enable the Visual Studio hosting process" option in Project Properties window. When this option is disabled, the settings string that added before will be empty. But after I enable this option, the settings string value will show.

[image]

Comment: i have just looked there and it is already checked.. don't know what to do.

Comment: Please reset your Visual Studio settings through Tools -> Import and Export settings -> Reset all settings. And then uncheck the "Visual Studio hosting process" option and clear your solution. Now re-checked this option and rebuild your application again.

Comment: It turns out that the opposite is true, i tried to run Debug when it's not checked and then it worked! so you still helped me but in reverse way haha.